# Intellij cant find Sqlite JDBC

Tags: java, database, sqlite, intellij-idea, jdbc

Im trying to connect to a sqlite database but for some reason intellij won't detect the driver. I have added it to my libraries and as a dependecy for my module and intellij even autofills the import but when building it gives the error "error: package org.sqlite does not exist"

[This person seemed to have the same issue](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/208382565-org-sqlite-JDBC-will-not-be-found) and for me it also worked about a week ago and now all of the sudden it decided not to work anymore. Could someone please help me?

Comment: How do yo include Sqlite jdbc driver dependency into the project?

Comment: File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Dependencies -> + Jar/Library (tried both) -> Apply

Comment: In a Gradle-based project you must not change the project structure settings, including the dependencies in the IDE UI settings. Instead, you should make corresponding configuration in the Gradle build file.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it by adding

```
implementation('org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc')
```

To the build.gradle file under dependencies